# Is the address of malloc + size_t * 3 aligned for any type?

Tags: c, malloc, memory-alignment

I'm builing a kind of dynamic array (vector), but instead of embedding the data (typically `void *`) into a `struct vector`, I'm reserving space for a `struct vector` + a chunk of bytes, an example using an array of `size_t`'s:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct vector {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t typesize;
    size_t size;
};

#define VECTOR(v) ((struct vector *)((unsigned char *)v - sizeof(struct vector)))

static void *valloc(size_t typesize, size_t size)
{
    struct vector *vector;
    unsigned char *data;

    data = calloc(1, sizeof(*vector) + typesize * size);
    if (data == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    vector = (struct vector *)data;
    vector->typesize = typesize;
    vector->capacity = size;
    vector->size = 0;
    return data + sizeof(*vector);
}

static void *vadd(void *data)
{
    struct vector *vector = VECTOR(data);
    unsigned char *new;
    size_t capacity;

    if (vector->size >= vector->capacity) {
        capacity = vector->capacity * 2;
        new = realloc(vector, sizeof(*vector) + vector->typesize * capacity);
        if (new == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        vector = (struct vector *)new;
        vector->capacity = capacity;
        vector->size++;
        return new + sizeof(*vector);
    }
    vector->size++;
    return data;
}

static size_t vsize(void *data)
{
    return VECTOR(data)->size;
}

static void vfree(void *data, void (*func)(void *))
{
    struct vector *vector = VECTOR(data);

    if (func != NULL) {
        for (size_t iter = 0; iter < vector->size; iter++) {
            func(*(void **)((unsigned char *)data + iter * vector->typesize));
        }
    }
    free(vector);
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t *data;

    data = valloc(sizeof(size_t), 1);
    if (data == NULL) {
        perror("valloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        data = vadd(data);
        if (data == NULL) {
            perror("vadd");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        data[i] = i;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vsize(data); i++) {
        printf("%zu\n", data[i]);
    }
    vfree(data, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The question is: Is the address of the result of `malloc` (`void *`) + the size of the `struct` well aligned for any type? Is the behaviour of this code well defined?

Comment: The only guarantee you have with [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) is that it returns a pointer to the first byte of a "memory block that is suitably aligned for any object type with [fundamental alignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object#Alignment)."

Comment: Also, can't you use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)? Together with [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) it might be easier to use?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, offsetof was my first attemp, but in this way it requires an extra member.

Comment: Note that given `struct vector *p = malloc(sizeof *p + more);`, `p+1` is necessarily a valid pointer: `p` is a pointer to at least one object of type `struct vector`, and pointer arithmetic is defined for a result that points one past the end of an array, including treating a single object as an array of one element. Furthermore, if `struct vector` contains a `size_t` member, then `p+1` must necessarily be suitably aligned for a `size_t`. But it is not necessarily suitably aligned for other types.

Comment: Why would it be a problem to have an extra member? You would still allocate roughly about the same amount of memory, and if you use an array of `max_align_t` members the start of the array should be suitably aligned by the compiler as it adds padding in the structure.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, no problem at all, in fact I'm going to use that method, but I was wondering if there was any alternative i.e: `max_align_t` (as pointed by @chux)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I am using your method: https://ideone.com/i1Wvsl , it works like a charm, thanks, am I using `offsetof` correctly in the macro?

Comment: @KeineLust That looks about right. But perhaps use a larger type for the array (like e.g. `max_align_t` as mentioned) as otherwise the compiler might not pad the structure and the array might end up with weird alignment. I would also recommend that you round up the amount of data to be allocated to the type of the array (i.e. with `max_align_t` round the byte-size to a multiple of `sizeof(max_align_t)`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, sorry but I don't get you you mean replacing `unsigned char data[]` with `max_align_t data[]`? or you mean making size in `valloc(size_t typesize, size_t size)` a multiple of `max_align_t`?

Comment: Rewrite the member in the structure as `max_align_t data[];` That will align the array to begin on a `max_align_t` boundary.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _otherwise the compiler might not pad the structure and the array might end up with weird alignment_ - I tought that a flexible array was properly aligned for any type!

Comment: Maybe. Actually I'm not quite sure about the details there. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thanks a lot!

Comment: Keine Lust,  The FMA alignment is properly aligned for the type of the array of that member.

Comment: @chux wooow, that makes a lot of sense, just one question, can I define `max_align_t data[];` and use pointer arihtmetic of different size than `sizeof(max_align_t)` i.e. with `sizeof(char)`  or `sizeof(double)` on the chunk of bytes? or it breaks the one past the last element of an array rule.

Comment: @KeineLust Yes, but it is easy to do it wrong.

Comment: @chux, thanks! does it break the one past the last element of an array rule? ie using an array of 37 chars? and in what sense it is easy to do it wrong? the interface will manage the stuff (`struct vector` is an opaque `struct` in the real implementation)

Comment: @chux I opened a new thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/55873051/1606345

Comment: FYI, the name `valloc` is in common use on Unix systems, and you will probably confuse people if you use this name for your function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is the address of malloc + size_t * 3 aligned for any type?

No, not certainly.

Make certain of *fundamental alignment* by making the prefix data also of *fundamental alignment*.

One way is to use of `union` of `struct vector` and `max_align_t`.  The size of `union uvector` will be a multiple of the *fundamental alignment*.

> `max_align_t` 
>   which is an object type whose alignment is as great as is supported by the implementation
>   in all contexts;

```
union uvector {
  max_align_t a;
  struct vector {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t typesize;
    size_t size;
  } v;
};

union uvector *uvector;
unsigned char *data;

data = calloc(1, sizeof *uvector ...
...
return data + sizeof *uvector;
```

---

Answer has some inefficiencies - Reworked in another answer..

Comment: Cosmetic remark: with C11 anonymous structs, we can do `struct {
    size_t capacity;
    size_t typesize;
    size_t size;
  };` And then access `uvector.capacity` directly instead of having to type `uvector.vector.capacity`.

Comment: *The sizeof `union uvector` will be a multiple of `max_align_t`.*  Pedantically, that will be true only if `sizeof( max_align_t ) >= sizeof( size_t` )`.  For example, an architecture with no alignment restrictions at all.

Comment: Typo: `return new + sizeof *uvector;` should be `return data + sizeof *uvector;` I think.

Comment: *The sizeof `union uvector` will be a multiple of `max_align_t`* doesn't make sense because `max_align_t` isn't a size. Perhaps you meant it is guaranteed to be a multiple of `_Alignof(max_align_t)`.

Comment: @chux: It's still wrong. It isn't guaranteed to be a multiple of `sizeof(max_align_t)`. It is guaranteed to be a multiple of `_Alignof(max_align_t)`.

Comment: @chux I mean just that sentence is wrong. The code itself is fine (although it could allocate up to `sizeof(max_align_t) - _Alignof(max_align_t)` more bytes than necessary).

Comment: @ian Reworded here and also provide a more [efficient answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55882939/2410359)

Answer (score 2):

> Is the address of malloc + size_t * 3 aligned for any type?

No, because there may be standard types which have greater alignment requirements than `size_t`. The alignment requirement of a standard type will be one of a number of *fundamental alignments* used by the compiler.

C11's `<stddef.h>` defines a standard type `max_align_t` whose alignment is as great as any standard type supported by the implementation. (There may be extended types that have a greater alignment requirement than `max_align_t`.) C11 also has the `_Alignof` and `_Alignas` keywords.

`_Alignof` is an operator that operates on a type and its result is an integer constant expression equal to the alignment requirement of that type in bytes. The largest *fundamental alignment* is given by `_Alignof(max_align_t)`.

The `_Alignas` keyword is used in *alignment specifiers* as part of a declaration to increase the alignment requirement of the declared object or member. (It cannot be used to decrease the alignment requirement of an object or member.)  An alignment specifier has one of the following forms:

- **`_Alignas`** `(` *type-name* `)`
- **`_Alignas`** `(` *constant-expression* `)`

where *constant-expression* specifies the required alignment in bytes.  The first form with *type-name* is equivalent to **`_Alignas`** `(`**`_Alignof`** `(` *type-name* `)` `)`.

You can use an alignment specifier to increase the alignment requirement of the first member of `struct vector` to the maximum fundamental alignment as follows:

```
struct vector {
    _Alignas(max_align_t)
    size_t capacity;
    size_t typesize;
    size_t size;
};
```

Since the first member of `struct vector` now has the greatest possible fundamental alignment, then `struct vector` as a whole has the same alignment requirement (unless it contains non-standard types that require *extended alignment*). If necessary. the compiler adds extra padding to the end of `struct vector` to ensure that `sizeof(struct vector)` is a multiple of `_Alignof(max_align_t)`.